# Mongoose query for fetching documents based on conditions and between certain dates

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a page which lists all the students data in front end. Currently I am fetching all the documents irrespective of their showStudentProfile status. Now, I need to fetch all the students from mongoDB using Mongoose query based on below conditions.

Conditions:

1. If `showStudentProfile === hide` && `owner === userId` (`userId` is the LoggedIn User), then fetch students list. i.e, he should be only able to fetch his own hidden documents.

2.If `showStudentProfile === custom`, then fetch only those documents if current date is between the `dateRange` field.

3. If `showStudentProfile === yes`, then fetch the documents.

Students schema is like below:

```
[{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc01"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "sub" : ["math", "generalScience"],
    "showStudentProfile" : "yes",
    "dateRange" : [],
    "owner": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc03"),
},{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc04"),
  "name" : "def",
  "sub" : ["physics", "chemistry"],
  "showStudentProfile" : "hide",
  "dateRange" : [],
  "owner": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc03"),
},{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc05"),
  "name" : "ghi",
  "sub" : ["math", "science"],
  "showStudentProfile" : "custom",
  "dateRange" : [ 
    "2020-07-28T11:14:50.652Z", 
    "2020-08-28T11:14:50.652Z"
],
  "owner": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc03"),
},{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc07"),
  "name" : "xyz",
  "sub" : ["physics", "chemistry"],
  "showStudentProfile" : "hide",
  "dateRange" : [],
  "owner": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc08"),
}]
```

My Attempt :

```
StudentModel.find({showStudentProfile:"hide", owner:"userId"})
```

But this will fetch only those documents whose `showStudentProfile` is hide and `owner` is `userId`. But I also need to fetch the documents whose `showStudentProfile` is `custom` and if `custom` and considering the currentDate, I need to fetch the documents which falls between the `dateRange` field.

Expected result if the `userId = ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc03")` and considering today's date:

```
[{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc01"),
    "name" : "abc",
    "sub" : ["math", "generalScience"],
    "showStudentProfile" : "yes",
    "dateRange" : [],
    "owner": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc03"),
},{
  "_id": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc04"),
  "name" : "def",
  "sub" : ["physics", "chemistry"],
  "showStudentProfile" : "hide",
  "dateRange" : [],
  "owner": ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc03"),
}];
```

Comment: If the answer helps you, please click on tick and upvote to help people who seek this kind of question

Answer (score 0):

You have three conditions, so you can get it from `$match` and `$or` combination
db.collection.aggregate([

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          owner: ObjectId("5f44af5a232afe415dc2bc03"),
          showStudentProfile: "hide"
        },
        {
          showStudentProfile: "custom",
          $expr: {
            $and: [
              {
                $lt: [
                  {
                    $toDate: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$dateRange",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  new Date()
                ]
              },
              {
                $gt: [
                  {
                    $toDate: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$dateRange",
                        1
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  new Date()
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          showStudentProfile: "yes"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```